# Can you use city/state to center Google map instead of Lat/Lng?

Tags: maps, google-geolocation

I am coding a site for a manufacturer with about 80 locations. I want to be able to center the map on the city/state of a location when it comes up in the modal.

I have the following two problems:

1. The coordinates for each location are not in the current site data
2. Attempting to use Google's Geolocation service to get the coordinates breaks all the pages

So I need to be able to just use city/state instead of Google's complicated Geoloc JSON/XML functions. Is this a thing? I can't find it anywhere.

```
var plant_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-plants'), {
    // zoom: 5,
    minZoom: <?php echo $zoomLevel ?>,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    mapTypeControl: false,
    // scaleControl: false,
    // disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

The code above is working fine, as the `$latitude` and `$longitude` data are coming from user cookies or input. But is there a way to use city/state to set the "center:" when coordinates are not available?

The alternative is manually getting the Lat/Long for each location to hard code into an array. Thanks!

Comment: I built out the array already. Any answers still welcome to help anyone else getting a migraine from this problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, basically, the [center](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.center) parameter only accepts `LatLng` or `LatLngLiteral`.

Since the `center` parameter is required to be able to instantiate the map, you might want to fetch for your user's location first before you instantiate the map.

After getting your user's location, you could use the detected geographical coordinates to center your map or you may want to check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58929392/10758035) from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569575/set-initial-center-and-zoom-in-google-maps-api/58929392#58929392) that demonstrates how to detect user location (using HTML5 Geolocation API), fetches its corresponding city address and sets the map's bounds to the city address' viewport.

I hope this helps!