# Set initial center and zoom in google maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If we open google map directly, the initial view is the our city, the city is zoomed and fitted in the whole screen.

If we create a map web app based on google maps API (without setting the center and zoom parameters), the initial view is blank.

The question is: how to make the map web app behave the same as google map (eg. display initial map view as the user's city being fitted in the whole screen)?

Looking forward to the answer, and expect as less code as possible.

For Bing Maps API, the city is fitted in view without setting the center and zoom of the map.

Comment: Are you referring to geolocating a user upon map initialization? Like in this example? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Comment: Not exactly. I expect the initial view of my map web app (using google map api) behaves the same to the one of google map. That means, if a user from New York opens the app, the initial view is New York city and the bounds of the city is zoomed and fitted the screen, Los Angeles user, LA is zoomed appropriately and takes the whole screen.

Comment: Since only the user's city is relevant, it is better to use fused location API (only if it exists). It needs to be approved by user if Geolocation is used.

Comment: Fused Location API is for mobile AFAIK. Also I fail to see why HTML5 Geolocation wouldn't fit your use case? You can always increase the initial zoom, use city bounds, set full map height+width... I recommend you go through JS API's guides and code samples https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples and determine for yourself what works best for you.

Comment: *Looking forward to the answer, and expect as less code as possible.* - when opening a question, we expect **you** to provide the code that you are using and with which you have issues. This question is **off-topic** to this website. A simple search on the web would answer that question in seconds.

Comment: The code is the "hello, world" sample from google map: "https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial". And the issue is that it always show the same initial view while we expect the initial view to be the user's city bound. _"A simple search on the web would answer that question in seconds."_ I spent days and failed. You could try to spend several seconds finding the answer.

Comment: The web app using Geolocation will pop up a dialog, "XXX wants to know your location", and users have to choose "allow" or "block". It is annoying. Besides, the center of the map should not be user's location. The user's city bound should be fitted in view no matter where the exact location is.

Comment: The result we expect is like this: "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/creating-and-hosting-map-controls/creating-a-basic-map-control". The user's city is fitted in view. And the interesting code is only one line: "var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap');". We don't have to set center or zoom.

Comment: Third, using map.setCenter() after setting center and zoom in options, there would be a jump from one location to the other visually. We expect that it is better to be initially set to the user's city.

Comment: Waiting for Google Map team members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you want the map to be initially set on the user's city. Based on this use case, it is necessary for us to know first which city is our users at. One way to detect that is by using HTML5's Geolocation API.

I understand that you find the pop up asking for a permission to be annoying, but note that as stated in Geolocation API's doc [(Item 4.1)](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/)

> User agents must not send location information to Web sites without the express permission of the user.

This is why the pop ups asking for permissions are required.

Assuming that you are fine with it (*you can always opt to use other user location detection strategy if you wish*), then, after getting your target user's location (in the form of geographical coordinates), you can use [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) to reverse geocode it. This will give us a list of addresses that were matched against these coordinates.

From this list of addresses, you could select the address which correspond to its city. Note that for this part, ***you may need to use different sets of components to align with the address formats used in different regions.***

As per this [doc](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingResponses), places with a type `locality` indicates an incorporated city or town political entity.

However, on some cases like in UK and in Sweden, the component to display the city is `postal_town`. Brooklyn is another special case as it uses `sublocality_level_1` to represent the city. I'm taking these special cases into consideration for my code sample below.

After selecting the city address, you could get its `location` and `viewport` and use that in the map that you will instantiate.

But please feel free to modify the code sample below based on your use case:

```
function initmap() {
// Get location first using HTML5 Geolocation API
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geocodePosition);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function geocodePosition(position) {
  var latlng = {
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude
  };

  // GB is the country code for United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Island
  // SE is for Sweden
  var specialCaseCountries = ['GB', 'SE'];
  var specialCaseState = ['Brooklyn'];
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var map;

  // reverse geocode the geographical coordinates from the Geolocation API
  geocoder.geocode({
    'location': latlng
  }, function(results, status) {
    // variable for the selected address that corresponds as the city
    var city;
    if (status === 'OK') {
      results.map(function(k, i) {
        results[i].address_components.map(function(a, b) {
          // checking if the result is included on the specialCaseCountries
          if (specialCaseCountries.includes(a.short_name)) {
            if (results[i].types.includes('postal_town')) {
              console.log('formatted address: ', results[i].formatted_address);
              city = results[i];
            }
            // checking if the result is included on the specialCaseState
          } else if (specialCaseState.includes(a.short_name)) {
            if (results[i].types.includes('sublocality_level_1')) {
              console.log('formatted address: ', results[i].formatted_address);
              city = results[i];
            }
            // other addresses
          } else {
            if (results[i].types.includes('locality')) {
              console.log('formatted address: ', results[i].formatted_address);
              city = results[i];
            }
          }
        });
      });
      // create a map that's centered on the selected adddress' location 
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: city.geometry.location,
        zoom: 10
      });
      // Set the viewport on the selected adddress' viewport
      map.fitBounds(city.geometry.viewport);

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Please find the working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d7r0mav4/)

Comment: Hi @annkylah, thank you very much for the answer. Actually, the question is meant to be raised to google map API team. I expect google map API shows the user's city when "center" is not set, since this is the exact behavior we use google map (detected by IP of course). It is hard and tedious for us to implement it.

Comment: For implementation issues, we normally redirect customers here (StackOverflow), so that the community could help as well. But if in case you encounter any issues or if you have feature requests regarding Google Maps Platform products, I suggest that you file an entry in **[our Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)**. Kindly make sure that you select the correct component (in your case, that would be on the 'JavaScript API' component). For your convenience, here's a quick link to the **[form](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207)**.